# dynamic width and FitText plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, fonts, resize

for some reason on my Site the FitText plugin doesn't work.
The Div width I creat with jquery like this:

```
$('.myContent').css({
position: 'relative',
float: 'left',
height: $('.target').height()-50,
width: $('.target').width()/3
});
```

the css for "myContent" looks like this:

```
div.myContent {
margin-top: 4em;
text-align: left;
font-size: 14pt;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
}
```

the content in my Div is like that:

```
<klein><fine>GEMÜSE</klein></fine> SURPRISE-MENU 
<strong>bio</strong><klein>geniessen</klein>
<stark> WEIN</stark> <klein> KERZENLICHT</klein>
```

and the little code for FitText.js

```
<script>
 jQuery("#myContent").fitText(4.2);
</script>
```

The Site URL: http://tinyurl.com/c6rkon7

thanks for any help, carol

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call it when your document is already loaded and ready to process.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myContent").fitText(4.2);
});
```